# delete line in vi

Tags: terminal, vim, vi

How can I delete a line in VI?

Here what I am doing right now:

1. Open up the terminal <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>t</kbd>
2. `vi a.txt`
3. I move my cursor to the line which I wan to delete, then **what key-combination is should use to delete line in vi editor**?

Comment: I suggest you read http://www.washington.edu/computing/unix/vi.html it gives you a basic usage overview. Here's a cheatsheet: http://www.tuxfiles.org/linuxhelp/vimcheat.html It's always a good idea to take a look at pages like that before asking trivial questions...

Comment: there's also S for deleting a line and entering insert

Answer (score 360, accepted):

Pressing `dd` will remove that line (actually it will cut it). So you can paste it via `p`.

Answer (score 23):

As others said, it's `dd` if you're in normal mode (press <kbd>ESC</kbd>) to ensure you are in normal mode, but by default, you will be. You may have found that vi doesn't act as you would expect an editor to act. It's pretty unique, and those unique features make it extremely powerful and fast to work with. If you want to learn more, you can run `vimtutor` at the command line, and you'll get a quick (maybe an hour worth of reading/experimenting) tutorial on the basics of how to use it.

Now, you can use an editor with a more familiar interface. Most systems have `nano`. You can type `nano a.txt` to open your file in `nano`. You can even go a step further - there isn't any reason you have to use a terminal-based editor. Since you mentioned using (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt+</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and this is the default shortcut in Ubuntu and some other Gnome distributions, so I'd be surprised if you didn't have `gedit` installed. At the command line, try `gedit a.txt` and you'll get a graphical editor.

Comment: A few people need it. If you edit text files regularly, it's worth the time to learn vim. If you don't, and you're just trying to follow some instructions to get something working, then it's probably not worth it unless you just interested in trying different software and learning new things.

Comment: I fired vimtutor at command line, and it opened up a vim, with a temp. file. Have I done any mistake?

Comment: @i-m-jm I don't think you've made a mistake, but your system might have an unusual configuration. It should open a document that begins "Welcome to the VIM Tutor". If you're interested in working through that, you should post another question.

Answer (score 15):

To delete the line under the cursor, use `dd`.

The delete command accepts all the normal positional modifiers, so if you are on the beginning of the line below the one you want to delete, you could just `dk` to go into delete mode and move up one line, deleting everything the cursor passed.

You can also specify repetition, so `5dd` will delete the line under the cursor five times, effectively deleting the current and following four lines.

Comment: Or `d5d`. I don't know why, but I prefer this. (Fun fact: `NdMd` deletes _N_ × _M_ lines)

Answer (score 8):

`Esc dd` after going to the line you want to delete

Comment: The escape is not necessary, if you can go to the line you want to delete.

Comment: Escape is needed if you use the arrow keys in insert mode to go to the right line.

Answer (score 2):

- `dd` delete (cut) a line and stay in the `COMMAND` mode.
- `S` delete (cut) a line and go to the `INSERT` mode.

Answer (score 1):

In visual mode,

shift+v, choose the lines, then d

ctrl+v, choose the columns, then d

Answer (score 0):

If you want to delete all lines containing a pattern, use `g/pattern/d`, for example:

```
:g/r[ea]gu.*r/d
```